# Expected score in marksmanship competition.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Problem:

Marksmanship competition at a certain level requires each contestant to take ten shots with each of two different handguns. Final scores are computed by taking a weighted average of 4 times the number of bullseye's made with the first gun plus 6 times the number gotten with the second. if Cathie has a 30% chance of hitting the bullseye with each shot from the first gun and a 40% chance with each shot from the second gun, what is her expected score?

Attempt: Let let $p_{1}$ =  chance of hitting the bullseye with each shot from the first gun.
                 $p_{2}$ = chance with each shot from the second gun

Then $E(X) = $4$p_{1}$ + 6$p_{2}$ =  $4(0.30) + 6(0.40)$ = $3.6$

Is this correct?

I am not sure. Any feedback would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of bull's eyes from the first gun, and $Y$ the number from the second gun.  We want $E(4X+6Y)$, which is $4E(X)+6E(Y)$.

Note that $E(X)=(10)(0.3)=3$ and $E(Y)=4$.

**Remark:** The number $X$ of bull's eyes from the first gun has binomial distribution $n=0$, $p=0.3$. So $E(X)=np$. Your answer had the right structure, but did not take into account the fact that $10$ shots are taken with each gun.

Comment: we multiply by $10$ because there are $10$ shots? We don't need to multiply $E(Y)$ by $10$ also? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I multiplied the $0.4$ for $Y$ by $10$, but skipped showing that step since I had already mentioned it for $X$,